# When to use send, sendDirect and sendDelayed in OMNet++?

Tags: omnet++

I am building my own compound module in omnet++ having multiple simple modules in it and having a layered architecture. But using only `send()` in inter-module communication (like the my App generator sends packet to below buffer using send()) seems to increase the total network latency.

Also, I have seen other well supported models like the inet, mixim etc. uses sendDirect and send and sendDelayed alternatively.

So, my question is, when to use `send()`, `sendDirect()` and `sendDelayed()` ?
And do they have any latency differences ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways to exchange information between modules. Which one you use depends really on what data you are passing and how much is that exchange related to the protocol itself.

First of all a clarification: Using `send()` or `sendDirect()` does **NOT** increase latency. If you send the message through a normal channel or use `sendDirect()` the message will be delivered to the destination module at the current simulation time (i.e. now). When the message is processed at the destination the simulation tine will be the same so there is no additional delay in simulation time. `sendDelayed()` obviously adds delay, but that is its main purpose anyway.

You have to decide whether you want to use message passing as the means of communication between modules (this is asynchronous) or you want to make direct calls into the other module (that is synchronous). In the first case, you can use OMNeT++'s scheduling functions (i.e. `send`, `sendDelayed`, `sendDirect` etc.). In the second case, you are usually calling directly into an other module by obtaining a pointer to it and probably casting it to its appropriate type using `check_and_cast<>`. Methods like `getParentModule()` and `findSubmodule()` are useful here to get a pointer to the desired module.

Direct calling is useful when the communication between the modules are deemed to 'implementation' detail. It is faster also (in terms of CPU usage) and synchronous (so you can get a return value).

If you pass along data that you want to inspect during the simulation using the GUI runtime-environment (i.e. you want to see the little dots flying around) then you should use message definitions and `send()`/`sendDirect()` etc.

Finally, the difference between `send()` and `sendDirect()`. If you have a topology where you connect the gates via channels (i.e. you now the communication path in advance) you usually use `send()` (e.g. a wired network). If you don't know the communication path in advance, then you are usually getting the pointer to the destination module, but after that you send an asynchronous message using `sendDirect()`. This is usually the case in wireless networks.