# Is there a way to sniff/listen an unicast packet/message on Omnet?

Tags: omnet++

I am doing development for WSN in Omnet. I want to sniff a unicast message but I don't have an idea how can i do it in Omnet. I made some research but i couldn't found any method for that

When I send data to another node, I am sending it as an unicast with this method :

```
cModule *nodeIndex = flatTopolojiModulu->getSubmodule("n", i);//n is array
sendDirect(new cMessage("msg"), nodeIndex, "in");
```

I am using `sendDirect` method because I am working on wireless network. According to this description : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36082721/5736731

`sendDirect` method is usually the case in wireless networks.

But when send message with sendDirect, a message is being handled by receiver node. For example, according to code example above:

if `i=2`, message that is sent only can handle by node which has index "2" from 
`void AnyClassName::handleMessage(cMessage *msg)` function

Answer (score 0):

An example of broadcasting messages can be found in [OMNeT++ Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:simple-modules:broadcasting-messages).

You should create only one instance of message that all nodes have to receive, and then send a new copy of this message to each node in loop. The [dup()](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:messages:duplicating-messages) method has to be used to create the copy of a message.

```
cMessage * msg = new cMessage("msg");
// totalN is the total number of nodes 
for (int i = 0; i < totalN; ++i) {
  cModule *nodeIndex = flatTopolojiModulu->getSubmodule("n", i);
  sendDirect(msg->dup(), nodeIndex, "in");
}
// original message is no longer needed
delete msg;
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice but i do not want to send broadcast or multicast message. Because energy of the each node is important for me. I am trying to develop energy efficient protocol. So i am sending message as unicast. I want to sniff a packet of unicast message. For example wireshark is doing this but i am working on WSN and i am using omnet that's way i am looking solution in omnet for packet sniffing in unicast transmission

Comment: What do you mean by _sniff_ a packet? Which element of node should sniff a packet? Consider that node A sends a message to node B: which node should sniff the message?

Comment: "Sniff" means "listening the  packet which is sending from A to B. For example, A is a sender node and B is a receiver node. Node C is "sniffer/listener" and it is between A and B. When I send packet from A to B, I want to "C" listens packet. In other word, "C" should overhear the packet and it can control the data of the packet which is sent from A to B. "C" should listen packet, even if I didn't send the packet directly to node C. Is it possible in Omnet?

Comment: Well, it is possible to do in OMNeT++, but it requires some changes of sending process. First of all, the message has to have a destination address filed (e.g. id of a node that should receive this message). Then, the message should be send to *all* nodes (i.e. broadcast). The non-sniffing node should check whether the address field is equal to own id, if not - the node removes the message. The sniffing node should receive and process this message. However, I don't understand how C may _control_ the data of the packet which is sent from A to B.